# Why is my 'li' not being added to the console?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to create a basic to do list app and the li in my code is not showing up in the console. I called li in the console to check and I get the error (Uncaught ReferenceError: li is not defined) but I'm confused because I thought I defined the li inside the function.

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="container">
    <form id="form-input">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="h2 mb-2" for="Enter Task">Enter Task</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="#taskInput" placeholder="Enter your task...">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <div class="task-list">
    <h3 class="mt-3">Task List</h3>
    <ul class="list-group">
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/732aafddc7.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

<!-- Javascript -->
// select elements 
const form = document.querySelector('#form-input');
const taskInput = document.querySelector('#taskInput');
const taskList = document.querySelector('ul.list-group');


function addTask(e) {

    // create element
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    // add class
    li.className = 'list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between';
    // create text node and append

    console.log(li);
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: When are you attempting to access the `li` variable in the console? Because it's a local variable, it will be undefined unless you attempt to access it from within the `addTask()` function (after it's declaration).

Comment: How/where do you call your `addTask()` function?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `addTask` function when you submit:

`form.addEventListener('submit', addTask);`

Otherwise, the form will perform the default behavior which is sending a request to the current page and reloading the page.

I'm assuming your javascript is actually in another file (app.js ?) and not just part of the html like it is written here.